# How can I trigger a function when I delete all the content from a textarea?

Tags: angular

To reproduce the problem enter text inside the text area until it expands. Once it has expanded select all text and hit delete.

Expected result is  Text area should shrink (if you press a key again it will)
But actually nothing happens.

I have attached all the possible events to the Text area

[Stack Blitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-benbd5)  **(Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.)**

```
    import { Component, Input, ChangeDetectorRef, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `
      <textarea class="commentText"
              cdkFocusInitial
              #commentTextArea
              [style.height]="textAreaHeight"
              (keyup)="textAreaResize()"
              (keydown)="textAreaResize()"
              (keypress)="textAreaResize()"
              (change)="textAreaResize()"
              (input)="textAreaResize()"
              (focus)="textAreaResize()"
              [maxLength]="300"
              [(ngModel)]="commentTextValue"
              placeholder="Type your Comment">
    </textarea>

  `,
  styles: [`
  .commentText {
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 59px;
  max-height: 100px;
  //height: 59px;
  border-radius: 4px !important;
  border: solid 1px #bab8b8 !important;
  //text-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #000000;
  padding: 6px;
  resize: none;
}
  `]
})
export class HelloComponent {

  commentTextValue: string;
  textAreaHeight: any;

  @ViewChild('commentTextArea', { static: false }) commentTextArea: ElementRef;

  constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {
  }

  textAreaResize() {
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();

    const textArea: HTMLTextAreaElement = this.commentTextArea.nativeElement;

    // console.log('textArea.scrollHeight', textArea.scrollHeight);

    if (this.commentTextValue) {
      if (this.commentTextValue.length < 107) {
        this.textAreaHeight = '59px';
      } else {
        const height = Math.max(57, Math.min(textArea.scrollHeight, 98));
        textArea.style.overflow = (textArea.scrollHeight > height ? "auto" : "hidden");

        this.textAreaHeight = height + 'px';
      }
    }



  }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added a check `if (this.commentTextValue)`, When you delete all texts, it doesn't get satisfied.

Add condition `|| this.commentTextValue == ""`

Like this:

`if (this.commentTextValue || this.commentTextValue == "")`

[Working stackbiltz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jfgiyj)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to detect changes in your textarea - is to use reactive forms. I added quite short code to yours to get a working sample - [Working Stackblitz Sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mpphfn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

**app.module.ts:**

```
  import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
  ...
  @NgModule({
     ...
     imports: [
        ReactiveFormsModule
     ],
     ...
  })
```

***.component.html:**

```
  <form [formGroup]="form">
      <textarea class="commentText"
          ...
          formControlName="textarea"
          placeholder="Type your Comment">
      </textarea>
  </form>
```

***.component.ts:**

```
  import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
  ...
  @Component({
     ...
  })
  export class HelloComponent {
     form: FormGroup;
     ...
     get textarea() { return this.form.get('textarea') as FormControl };
     ...
     constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.form = this.fb.group({
           textarea: [null]
        });
        ...
        this.textarea.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
           if (!this.textarea.value) {
              console.log('no text!');
           } else {
              console.log('oh, there are some chars in the textarea!');
           }
        });
     }
     ...
  }
```

Works to me) Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but your code doesn't expand the textarea as in my code

Comment: Updated the sample. Now the textarea expands by entering and shrinks by deleting any char.

Answer (score 0):

I propose: 1) use keyup, 2) pass the event to the handler, 3) check both event.target.value and event.key. Something like

```
<textarea class="commentText" (keyup)="textAreaResize($event)"> 

<!-- ... -->


textAreaResize(event) {
    if ((event.key === 'Delete' || event.key==='Backspace') && event.target.value.length === 0 ) {
// here resizing should happen
}
```